# Parse Error when using const?

Tags: php, oop, yii, constants, syntax-error

Can someone tell me how to fix this error?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /path/folders/etc/domain/protected/controllers/SiteController.php
>   on line 6

This is what's on line 6:

```
const URL = Yii::app()->params['url'];
```

This works, but I need to define all parameters in a single config file, which is why I changed it to the code above:

```
const URL = 'http://domain.com/file.php';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PHP: constant - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

A constant is by definition, constant. If you need to give it a computed value, use a variable instead.

Comment: Agree with Mathieu, it also makes your code untestable since you can't provide different values for the constant.